# remove duplicate column from dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I need to remove one column from the DataFrame having another column with the same name. I need to remove only one column and need the other one for further usage.

For example, given this input DF:

```
sno | age | psk | psk
---------------------
 1  |  12 |  a4 | a4
```

I would like to obtain this output DF:

```
sno | age | psk
----------------
 1  |  12 |  a4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RDD` is the way (but **you need to know the column index of the duplicate columns for removing duplicate columns back to `dataframe`**)

If you have `dataframe` with duplicate columns as

```
+---+---+---+---+
|sno|age|psk|psk|
+---+---+---+---+
|1  |12 |a4 |a4 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

You know that the last two column index are duplicates.

Next step is for you to have column names with duplicates removed and form `schema`

```
val columns = df.columns.toSet.toArray
val schema = StructType(columns.map(name => StructField(name, StringType, true)))
```

Vital part is to convert the `dataframe` to `rdd` and remove the required column index (here it is the 4th)

```
val rdd = df.rdd.map(row=> Row.fromSeq(Seq(row(0).toString, row(1).toString, row(2))))
```

Final step is to convert the `rdd` to `dataframe` using `schema`

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---+---+
|sno|age|psk|
+---+---+---+
|1  |12 |a4 |
+---+---+---+
```

I hope the answer is helpful